# Filter Array of Objects based on input field in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

Got in a rather troublesome situation 
I have an array of objects

```
[
   {
     "title":"placeholder",
     "text":"placeholder"
   },
   {
     "title":"test",
     "text":"placeholder"
   },
   {
     "title":"javascript",
     "text":"placeholder"
   }
]
```

I am displaying them in a div,but thats not important
I got an input field which users should type in title's and as they type the array should only show matching object. 
Inputing java would show the javascript titled object

I need to somehow change the array so it doesnt display anything but the entered title and if the input is empty shows the whole array

I am using React but i can only use hooks
So i copy the json

```
var [arrayOfObjects, setArray] = useState(Json)
```

the Json is imported from a local file
arrayOfNotes is the array that i need to change
pointing out so its easier to understand

ty in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Have you gotten any further than this? Do you have state for your input text value?

Comment: well i have the whole thing done  but this filter function, i can either either copy the input value into a variable with a simple a=docume.getelbyid().value, or i can set the input value into a state, i am ok with that,my problem maybe explained in a better way:
for example having 2 objects with titles "javascript" and "javasssssscript", i can get it to show 1 of them by entering "javasc" or "javass" but if the user deletes the "s" from "javass" and gets "javas" i still have only 1 showing,cant get back the other 1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is what you're looking for.

Here's what your component might looks like.

```
const List = ({ data }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <input 
        type="text"
        value={value} 
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} 
      />

      {data
        .filter(item => {
          if (!value) return true
          if (item.title.includes(value) || item.text.includes(value)) {
            return true
          }
        })
        .map(item => (
          <div>
            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
            <p>{item.text}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

And you pass your json data to that component

```
<List data={Json} />
```

[Here's a working example of the above code](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-butterfly-e8hlz)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't share your component so I'll assume you know how to get the input value and call the corresponding variable `input`, besides you have your original array, from your example I judge it is called `Json`.

Then you can filter your value as follows:

```js
const [arrayOfObjects, setArray] = useState(Json);
const filteredArray = input ?
    originalArray.filter(item => item.title.includes(input) :
    originalArray;
```

So that later you can render the `filteredArray` as follows:

```
<ul>
  {filteredArray.map(item => (<li>{item.title}</li>))}
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need a `filteredArray` state. You could just filter it directly in `render`

Comment: True if you always have access to the initial state of `Json`. Not so if this `Json` comes for a server request, or such.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from. The point is to display the filtered results, and for that you don't ever need a second piece of state. You just need to call `filter` in `render`

Comment: But how will you get to the original state after the user enters some value and erases it?

Comment: There is only ever original state, that's my point. In fact you don't even need any state for the array to do what the OP is asking, you could just as well do it by filtering props

Comment: From the question I don't know where it comes from. You are right in case it comes from props.

Comment: It doesn't matter where it comes from I keep saying, what I'm trying to say is that you only need to filter in render which doesn't change the original data in any way no matter where it comes from

Comment: The json is coming from a local file so thats not the problem, yea,changing only the render would be the perfect way to make this work
will try @dmigo suggestion and check yours too

Comment: I posted an answer of what I mean

Comment: I second with @azium, most of the times we just need to store the original array and the input search value. Those two are enough, the result list is just a filtered list from the original array